# Hadoop Kerberos failure on Spark local

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm getting the following error when running `spark-submit` on Gitlab.

This works locally, but not on Gitlab.

```
21/11/03 05:34:51 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:67)
```

Why would this happen?

```
pipenv run spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:    spark-avro_2.12:3.2.0 --master local[1] --conf spark.jars.    ivy=/tmp/.ivy main.py
```

Comment: Can you run "klist" command and verify Kerberos ticket listed?

Comment: Where would kerberos be coming from if I'm running in isolated env? Do I need to install for something like unit tests?

Comment: if I were to guess based on a very vaguely stated question, it may come from `core-site.xml` which specifies `hadoop.security.authentication` property to be `kerberos`.

Comment: Is there a recommended default to set this to when running inside of some testing environment like github/gitlab?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am bumping into the same issue when running in an isolated environment on Jenkins.